# SQL percentage usage calculation using 2 columns

Tags: sql, percentage

Trying to get the percentage usage for a report based on the following columns:

```
Dept Ext   Sec1 Sec2 StartDate            EndDate
---------------------------------------------------------------
1    1234  5    5    2017-05-01:08:00:00  2017-05-04:08:00:10
2    1230  8    8    2017-05-01:09:10:00  2017-05-04:09:10:11
1    1234  15   15   2017-05-02:08:01:00  2017-05-04:08:01:20
```

I need to display the percentage time the user spent on the phone, based on the total seconds in Sec1, for the time period. If needs be, I can create a 3rd column with the percentage total as part of the creation job (the final table is generated form a join query of 2 other tables). Thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: So you are saying that user 1230 spent 8 of 11 seconds on the phone and you want to see 73% in the result row? And for user 1234 you want two result rows or one total?

Comment: Is it 11 seconds for user 1230? Or 3 days and 11 seconds? (2017-05-01 vs 2017-05-04)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the end result. That is way easier to read

Comment: Moreover: Why does the result only contain user 1234? Why only their first entry? Why 0.01? How do you calculate?

Comment: I think I am overthinking this - I will as part of the createdb query create two columns called totalsec and perc - I will then update column TotalSec with whatever the total nr of seconds are for set totalsec=sum(sec1)

Perc will then be:

Set perc=Sec1/Totalsec*100

Will this work ??

Comment: OK .. so I know have a TotalSec column and the question has changed - will close this and see if I can get the Report Builder to calculate the percentage for me as the query percentage works out to 0,0000000000000000000000something ...... and sql don't like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add these lines to my creatDB query to get the right results:

alter table compinfo.dbo.pabxreport add TotalSec Int
alter table compinfo.dbo.pabxreport add TotalPer Decimal(14,8)

update compinfo.dbo.pabxreport
set TotalSec= (
select sum(billsec1) from pabxreport)

update compinfo.dbo.pabxreport
set TotalPer= (billsec1 * 100.00 / Totalsec)